# Github desktop returns error about comand not found with husky

Tags: git, github, github-desktop, husky, git-husky

[image]

I am new with husky. I can make commits in git cmd using the git commands and all, but i want to use gitgub desktop for it.

I have an application using `"husky": "^7.0.4"`, and `Github desktop Version 2.9.6`.

I couldn't find a solution for it. i have seen some git Issues about it, but i was not able to solve it.

https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3701#issuecomment-375905661

https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/1072

Anyone have ever found this, and could help me pls?